# Pushing a DirectX object into a std::queue

Tags: c++, directx, std

I'm working on a small release manager that will be used to delete objects once they are old.

I'm using a `std::queue` to hold the age & pointer to the object.

This is the method that I'm using to push values into the queue:

```
ID3D12Resource* texture; // declaration
renderPlat->PushToReleaseManager(texture);

std::queue<std::pair<int,void*>> mResourceBin; // declaration
void RenderPlatform::PushToReleaseManager(ID3D12Resource* res)
{
    if (!res)
        return;
    mResourceBin.push(std::pair<int, void*>(0, res));
}
```

But this is causing an *Exception thrown: read access violation* / `std::_Deque_alloc<std::_Deque_base_types<std::pair<int,void * __ptr64>,std::allocator<std::pair<int,void * __ptr64> > > >::_Myoff(...) returned 0x6B0` :

```
void push_back(value_type&& _Val)
    {   // insert element at end
    this->_Orphan_all();
    _PUSH_BACK_BEGIN;  // <--- The exception is thrown here!!!
    this->_Getal().construct(
        _Unfancy(this->_Map()[_Block] + _Newoff % _DEQUESIZ),
        _STD forward<value_type>(_Val));
    _PUSH_BACK_END;
    }
```

The object that I'm trying to delete, is an [ID3D12Resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn788699%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) it inherits from [IUnknown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509(v=vs.85).aspx)

Edit:

I'm using: ***Visual Studio 2015 (v140)***.

Edit 2:

The ID3D12Resource* object passed to the PushToReleaseManager() is created using [ID3D12Device::CreateCommittedResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn899178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: What is  `_PUSH_BACK_BEGIN` ?  You have a lot of "hidden" code, please post a [mcve].

Comment: @RichardCritten: The code shown is inside msvc's standard library implementation

Comment: @MikeMB: The second code snippet is inside MSVC, but we can't even see the definition of mResourceBin, or any of the other references to it (my guess is that there is some memory corruption going on).

Comment: @MartinBonner: Completely agree, and I actually voted to close the question until a msvc is provided.

Comment: @Nacho.  You now have three comments and two close votes saying "you haven't shown us enough code to be able to help you".  You are going to have to show some more code (and put some serious work into reducing the size), or do some careful debugging.

Comment: @Nacho: Although not impossible, it is rather unlikely that the error is within hte standard library implementation, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to post the implementation of std::queue / std::deque. Other parts of the code that read/write from the queue howver might be important. Most probably however, you have to build up a new mcve from the ground up

Comment: @MartinBonner , just added the declaration of the container, my visual studio and tool set as well as the macro.

Comment: Does your application use multiple threads? Also how you actually "delete" it later?

Comment: @MikeMB , I agree with that, just wanted to post the std code in case the way I'm using it was wrong or invalid.

Comment: @VTT, it is just one thread, the object is released with the IUnknown::Release() method, but the application is crashing before reaching that point.

Comment: Then the problem is most likely caused but the rest of the code causing `mResourceBin` corruption or something.

Comment: I added more info about how I'm calling to this methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
I was getting the RenderPlatform which has the PushToReleaseManager() method like this:

```
auto rPlat = (dx11on12::RenderPlatform*)(renderPlatform);
```

This cast was failing because renderPlatform was invalid and it was returning a null pointer. The thing is that I was allowing me to call the method no problem, I guess because it had some junk memory around.

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score -3):

Try to use smart pointers. They are much better then explicitly try to release memory.

Comment: Hi, the thing is that I would like to manage when it will be released, that's why I'm using just raw pointers in this case.

Comment: Unless the OP provides a lot more information that shows there error is actually due to manual memory management this is a comment at best, but certainly not an answer.